# XPages error while copying NotesRichTextItem to other document

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

In one of my XPages, I have written the following code to copy the content of one rich text item into another. Both rich text items are within different documents.

```
var docChild : NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
docChild.replaceItemValue("Form", "Child");
var rt_Parent : NotesRichTextItem = docParent.getDocument().getFirstItem("Body_1");
var rt_Child : NotesRichTextItem = docChild.createRichTextItem("Body");
rtChild.appendRTItem(rtParent)
```

Here docParent is the document associated with current XPage (as data source). When trying to execute the code, I am getting the following error:

**Method NotesRichTextItem.appendRTItem(lotus.domino.local.Item) not found, or illegal parameters**

Someone guide me how to fix the issue, and what is the proper way to copy an RT item from one document to another (field name of RT item is different in source and destination documents).

Thanks

Romil

Comment: Probably mixup of imports. Make sure all classes are from the same package, lotus.domino.* preferably.

Comment: There's also Item.copyItemToDocument(targetDoc, newItemName). On the down side: "file attachments, embedded objects, and object links that are contained within the rich-text item are not copied to the destination document". If they are copied using appendRTItem? I sure hope so.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a typo. This should work:

```
rtChild.appendRTItem(rt_Parent)
```

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't 'rtParent' be null object - and definitely no 'lotus.domino.local.Item' object?